# Should I keep namespace for nested REST API resources

Tags: api, rest

Let's say I have following tables: `articles`, `article_comments`, `profiles`, `profile_comments`.

I also have following routes:

`GET /api/article_comments`

`DELETE /api/article_comments/123`

`PUT /api/article_comments/123`

etc.

The question is should I keep `article_` part in case of accessing the resource as nested:

`PUT /api/articles/123/article_comments/987`

or

`PUT /api/articles/123/comments/987`

?

Comment: A little late to the party, but I would go with `/api/articles/123/comments/987` as the namespace is already clear with `/api/articles/123`.